# Variance of Integral of Second Order Stationary Process

Tags: probability

**Problem**: Let $X(t)$ be a second order stationary process, $-\infty<t<\infty$. Show that $Var(\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}X(t)dt) = \frac{2}{T}\int_{0}^{T}r_X(t)(1-\frac{t}{T})dt$ for $T>0$.

**My attempt at a solution**:
$Var(\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}X(t)dt) = \mathbf{E}[\frac{1}{T^2}\int_{0}^{T}X(t)dt\int_{0}^{T}X(s)ds]$

$$=\frac{1}{T^2}\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{T}\mathbf{E}[X(t)X(s)]dsdt$$
$$=\frac{1}{T^2}\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{T}r_X(s,t)dsdt$$

Next, I think it would be relevant to use the fact that $r_X(s,t) = r_X(0,t-s)$ for a second order stationary process $X(t)$. I'm not sure how this would allow me to evaluate one of the integrals, though.

Comment: *Hint.* Split the integral according to whether $t < s$ or $t > s$, and then use the symmetry of $r$ to write it as $$ \operatorname{Var}\left( \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} X(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right) = \frac{2}{T^2} \int_{0}^{T} \int_{0}^{t} r_X (s, t) \, \mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t. $$ Then you can use the stationarity of $r_X$ and a simple application of Fubini's theorem to prove the claim.

Comment: I split the integral as you said, and obtained 
$$ \frac{1}{T^2}\int_{0}^{T}(\int_{0}^{T}r_X(s)ds + \int_{t}^{T}r_X(t)ds)dt$$
$$ = \frac{1}{T^2}(\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{t}r_X(s)dsdt + \int_{0}^{T}r_X(t)(T-t)dt$$

The second integral evaluates to half of the answer I need, so I assume that the first integral should evaluate to something identical. Using Fubini's, however, leaves me with an integral with respect to $s$ of $r_X(s)$, so I don't know how to simplify it further.

Comment: Never mind. I got it. I needed to get the new limits of integration right when applying Fubini's to the first integral.